# parse variable as Jade tag

Tags: javascript, html, pug

Is it possible to parse JS variable as Jade tag? What I am trying to achieve is basicaly:

```
- var tag, numnodes = X
- if (numnodes == 2) tag=".span2"
- else tag=".span3"
tag
 <do something here>
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use interpolation

```
- var tag = true ? "span" : "div";
#{tag}
  blala
```